# Node.js can't make request to zomato.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, http-get

I would like to make request to https://zomato.com/ but there is no response, I am able to connect anywhere else but not to zomato I get timeout error every time. I was trying to set user-agent but it didn't work. I use node 6.6.0 and request 2.79.0. Any ideas?

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

request.get({
    url: 'http://zomato.com/',
    headers: {
        'user-ggent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'
      }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
  }
});
```

---

**Update:**
I've noticed that this:

```
curl -X GET "https://zomato.com/"
```

returns 301 redirect

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems trying to do something similar with some websites. Try [NigthmareJS](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) instead of *request*

I didn't tested for zomato but here there is the code that I used for another website:

```
var website = new Nightmare()
.useragent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36")
.goto('http://zomatoorwhateverwebsite.com/')
.evaluate(function(){
    return document.documentElement.innerHTML;
})
.end()
.then(function(html) {
   var $ = cheerio.load(html);

   //Do what you need here
})
```

I hope this helps. Sometimes you need to add some wait() check the documentation for extra functions

Comment: Html argument is null every time. I'm pretty sure this is some their security trick for not scraping their site but I have no idea how it works. Btw, I've discovered that postman without any extra headers works great.

Comment: Yes. I had the same problem with tripadvisor... I am pretty sure zomato uses an API sometimes it is difficult to scrap websites that use API because the HTML is, for example if they use angular, <ul ng-repeat="line in lines"><li>{{line.text}}</li></ul>but without the call to the API that means nothing. Maybe try checking the network calls on dev tools sometimes you can figure out how the calls to the api are made and then it is easy to get the data. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

if you look at the output of curl zomato.com -v you can see that we are being redirected :

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

So we need to add :

```
 followAllRedirects: true,
```

Here :

```
 request.get({

     url: 'http://zamato.com/',
     followAllRedirects: true,
     headers: {
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'
      }
```

Comment: I was able to get the program to respond with '200' now , are you still having an issue ?